# NodeJS in production app stops returning responses at random point

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-rds

So I have a NodeJS backend app, deployed with docker on an EC2 instance, with connection to AWS RDS mysql database, at some random point the app receives requests but never returns response back,check the following logs (format: time endpoint response-status response-time response-body-size)

```
14:26:02 "PUT /api/invoices/collect" 200 11 ms 4
14:26:02 "GET /api/invoices/47158" 200 25 ms 2266
14:26:19 "GET /api/invoices/customer/1488?type=ITEMS_INVOICE" 200 5 ms 2
14:26:20 "GET /api/items/company/1?isActive=true" 200 10 ms 5286
14:27:20 "GET /api/plans/?isActive=true" 200 13 ms 3644
14:28:57 "PATCH /api/users/1488/plans" - - ms -
14:29:04 "PATCH /api/users/1488/plans" - - ms -
14:29:07 "GET /api/level3-addresses/" - - ms -
14:29:08 "PATCH /api/users/1488/plans" - - ms -
14:29:28 "PATCH /api/users/1488/plans" - - ms -
14:29:29 "GET /api/level3-addresses/" - - ms -
```

to make it work again I need to restart the image (which runs `node dist/src/main` again)
`docker-compose restart backend`
then the app works normally again.
I tried to increase the EC2 instance type, but still getting same problem.

Comment: How long does it run before stopping responding? Is this time consistent, or is it related to the request volume? Does it happen consistently after a specific request? Would increasing the instance memory increase this time to failure?

Comment: no specific time for it to happen, sometimes once in two weeks, other times it can happen again in 2 days. No specific action causing it. Increasing the instance memory is not related to how much time it could take to stop again

Comment: Doesn't sound like a memory leak but I still suggest monitoring instance memory usage in case there's a correlation; this may be related to storage also (monitor log storage). If you're using Express you could set a timeout for the server/route in case it's a code issue or db hang. How are you connecting to the EC2 server; is there a WAF or API Gateway?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.